# wxWidgets with visual studio 2015

Tags: wxwidgets

I finish installing wxWidgets and build accordingly it give no problem.
I started a new project and adding the path to library and include and build this project it gives no problem, it works very well.
But When I run it give the error as wxbase31ud_vc_x64_custom.dll missing but actually this dll is there in the library folder.

what to do?
Help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Are you trying to run from within the IDE? Another alternative is to add the wxWidgets DLL path to the environment variables in the debugging options for the project. But this will only work from the IDE if you release your executable you need to follow Jon's answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to load, a DLL must be in the application load path.  It is not sufficient for it to be in the same directory as the import library.  The safest thing to do is to place the DLL files in the same location as your executable.  My personal preference is to statically link wxWidgets.

Comment: Notice that instead of copying DLLs into the application directory, which is going to quickly get annoying if you have several applications, you can also run the application from the directory containing the DLLs as current directory is part of the DLL load path under Windows.